# Modify the content inside the SOAP envolope body using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a scenario, where i have to only alter the value(serverURL) of one attribute inside the SOAP body and leave the rest intact.

I am not able to find a solution for it. please help.

XML file is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loginResponse>
         <result>
            <metadata>xxx</metadata>
            <passwordExpired>xx</passwordExpired>
            <sandbox>xx</sandbox>
            <serverUrl>xx</serverUrl>
            <userId>xx</userId>
            <userInfo>
               <accessibilityMode>xx</accessibilityMode>
            </userInfo>
         </result>
      </loginResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XSLT File is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*|@*|text()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="serverUrl">
    <serverUrl>https://Sahoo/Nrusingha</serverUrl>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Your XSLT succesfully changes the value of the `serverUrl` element to `"https://Sahoo/Nrusingha"` and leaves  everything else as is.

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried using this online tool http://xslttest.appspot.com and the same xslt did not work for me. I think, something is going wrong somewhere. It only copied the whole message and did not change the serverUrl field.

Comment: You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/bwdwt3

Comment: Thanks Mike, it works fine in the test url you have given. But i am bot sure why it does not work in the other url. If i test using xmlspy, it does not work for me as well. Is there any xsl version on both the urls please?

Comment: It works perfectly well in any XSLT 1.0 conforming processor. If you're seeing something else then either your code is different or the processor is non-conforming.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it works fine. Appreciate your help.